# How to round a number at other threshold than 0.5

Tags: javascript, if-statement, rounding

How would I go about changing this code so that the number 7 can be replaced with any number between 7 and 16?

```
    var lvalue = $( ".leave-input" ).val();
    if (lvalue <=  7.29) {
      lvalue = roundDown();
    } else if (lvalue >= 7.3) {
      lvalue = roundUp();
    }
```

I am trying to round the time the user input ups the nearest hour. I had trouble using time so am now just using the number they input.

To clarify rather then having an if statement for each number, 7, 8, 9 etc. Is there a way to rewrite the current code so "7" can be any number between 7 and 16?

Comment: Is `7.29` meant to represent "7 hours and 29 minutes"? Anyway, if you add `0.2` to the number, you should be able to use `Math.floor()` and `Math.ceil()`.

Comment: Yes it is, I tried with time input and I was having a nightmare getting other parts of the code to work. The functions roundDOwn and roundUp use Math.floor and Math.ceil. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Since you're editing the question title, might I suggest something along the lines of "How to round a number at other threshold than 0.5"

Comment: Will do, thank you Chris, I struggle with wording a lot of the time lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it so that the number is smaller than 1, then it should work for all cases:

```js
let lvalue = $(".leave-input").val();
const baseValue = Math.round((lvalue - Math.floor(lvalue)) * 100) / 100;
if (baseValue<= 0.29) {
    lvalue = roundDown();
} else if (baseValue>= 0.3) {
    lvalue = roundUp();
}
```

Here is a working example:

```js
function calculate() {

  let lvalue = Number(document.getElementById('input').value)
  const baseValue = Math.round((lvalue - Math.floor(lvalue)) * 100) / 100;
  if (baseValue <= 0.29) {
    lvalue = Math.floor(lvalue);
  } else if (baseValue >= 0.3) {
    lvalue = Math.ceil(lvalue);
  }

  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = lvalue;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" />
<button onClick="calculate()">Round</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Well it rounds any number up, but it wont round back down :/ I apologise, should of tested both ways before replying.

Comment: Hmmm in the example it works, no? If you enter `4.2` and you press the button, the output is `4`.

Comment: Hmm could be user error. Apologies I'll check I added it right and try again, thank you.

Comment: This doesn't work; enter 7.3 and the result is 7.3 (I have no idea why though, Firefox)

Comment: Indeed, I fixed it. There was an issue with how the `baseValue` was being calculated. It should work now.

Comment: It should also work if you `parseInt` the `.value` (when it's still a string).

Comment: @ChrisG That will use the base-10 rounding rules (so `4.3` will be rounded down to `4` instead of `5`, as the OP expects)

Comment: I meant for getting the baseValue, not the end result. It's much shorter.

Comment: Thank you, with some id editing I got this to work exactly how I need it to. I marked this answer as accepted but am also up voting the others as they all work, but as this was first I think it's only right to do so. Thank you for your time and helping with this.

Answer (score 3):

If you add `0.2` to the value, you can use `Math.round()`:

```js
input.oninput = function() {
  let lvalue = +document.getElementById('input').value + 0.2;
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = Math.round(lvalue);
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text">
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let lvalue = $(".leave-input").val();

const integer = Math.trunc(lvalue);
const decimal = lvalue % 1;// or you could do lvalue - interger
if (integer >= 7 && integer <= 16) {
    if (decimal <= 0.29) {
        lvalue = roundDown();
    } else if (decimal >= 0.3) {
        lvalue = roundUp();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(".leave-input").change(function(){
  let lvalue = parseFloat($(".leave-input").val());
  const val = lvalue * 100 % 100 ;                
  if (val <= 29) {
      lvalue = Math.floor(lvalue);//roundDown();
  } else {//your condition will skip anything between .29 and .30
      lvalue = Math.ceil(lvalue);//roundUp();
  }
  $(".result").html(lvalue);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="leave-input" />
<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: @ChrisG ... javascript . Updated with other way